# Python: How detect text in a plainTextEdit and only then enable a button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

in my Qt application I have a `plainTextEdit` box into which I expect the user to enter the serial number of the hardware for which he wants the python/Qt application to generate a report. So, the HW Serial Number is a must input for my application, if he doesn't enter that then I don't want to enable the Report Generate `pushButton`.

1. How can I detect that he has entered some text in the box? Then enable the button?
2. How to detect if he completely erases what he has entered? Then disable the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the [`textChanged()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#textChanged) signal of `QPlainTextEdit`. This will be fired whenever the text changes. You can then access the contents of the `QPlainTextEdit` through [`toPlainText()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop) and use it to decide whether to enable or disable the button.

Here's a simple example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.edit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.edit, QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'), self.handleTextChange)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Generate Report')
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def handleTextChange(self):
        self.button.setDisabled(self.edit.toPlainText() == '')


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```